# Store translation in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, locale

I have some categories for product.

As these categories can change or grow I think I'll store them in a database in order to manage them through an admin interface.

However, these categories must be translated in another language. (en/fr/maybe other...)

In that way, I would like to know your thought on this:

- Is it better to set these categories in the Category model (in an array) and translate it through a yml file
- Did I have to set up a catagory database with locale columns, for example like this:

  id (category id) | en (english translation) | fr (french translation) | etc...
- Or Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I've never done localization myself but have you checked out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html ?

Comment: Definitely start with the internationalization guide. It's one of those things where you don't want to roll your own if you don't have to. The hard problems have already been largely solved by the people who are experts at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

What I suggest is if you're translating content that belongs to the model (e.g. attribute names) and that you will control if/when they change, go with a YAML file per locale.

For dynamic content, use a database.

As show in section 6.1 "Different backends" at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-backends you can mix both strategies : look for the translation in the database and if it isn't found, fall back onto the YAML files.